# compiling opencv using namespace alias

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, static-libraries

We need to completely merge opencv libs into our custom library.

(We are able to do this with boost using namespace aliasing by using bcp for example: dist/bin/bcp --namespace=customboost --namespace-alias *module-list* )

On similar lines, do we have an easy way to completely wrap the opencv into a custom namespace?

We want to do this because the opencv is a statically linked implementation detail into our customer facing custom lib (again static). We do not want the cv symbols exported from our custom lib to collide with the global space.

Comment: Somehow related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1121052/2436175 (Although this was asked before the `cv` namespace was introduced)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative method to namespace aliases could be taking OpenCV source code, and replace any occurrency of cv (namespace) with a new custom namespace name.

Using regex, you would replace:

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9_])cv([^a-zA-Z0-9_])
```

With:

```
$1myCv$2
```

Explanation: cv, preceded and followed by any character not in the set `a-zA-Z0-9_`. The parentheses in the matching expression and the `$1` and `$2` in the substitution expression serve the purpose to put back the preceding and following character in place.

Example:

```
#ifdef HAVE_OPENCL

namespace cv
{
namespace ocl
{
${nested_namespace_start}

")

cv::try
cv_wontsubstitute
```

Becomes:

```
#ifdef HAVE_OPENCL

namespace myCv
{
namespace ocl
{
${nested_namespace_start}

")

myCv::try
cv_wontsubstitute
```

---

A different even crazier idea could be to compile both your library and opencv defining a macro

```
#define cv myCv
```

Letting the preprocessor rename the OpenCV namespace. Practically speaking, you will invoke the compiler with `-D cv=myCv`

Comment: Thank you @Antonio, I finally ended up doing something very similar using sed. Inspired by boost bcp utility, I ended up providing namespace alias as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike boost bcp, there isn't any native utility provided by OpenCV. But this is a fairly easy task that can be achieved using regular expressions.

This works and now I have compiled version of OpenCV using mycustomcv namespace

```
find . -type f -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.hpp' -o -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cmake'  -o -name '*.py'| xargs sed -i '/using/! s/\<namespace cv\>/namespace mycustomcv{} namespace cv = mycustomcv; namespace mycustomcv/g'
```

After running the script, the namespace changes from `namespace cv {...}` to

```
namespace mycustomcv{} namespace cv = mycustomcv; namespace mycustomcv 
{ 
  //whatever
}
```

while skipping `using namespace cv;` declarations.

As an example, the name mangled symbols look like this,

```
_ZZN8mycustomcv25getMorphologyColumnFilterEiiii // namespace mycustomcv 

_ZZN8cv25getMorphologyColumnFilterEiiii  // namespace cv
```

Comment: Brilliant solution!